# How to detect if /norestart is provided running msi

Tags: windows, windows-installer

I'm building MSi using visual studio setup project. I want to have different custom action run depending on /norstart option. What condition should I use to detect if /norestart is provided or not?

If this is impossible, I'm thinking about setting a property. Here is my theory. Use Orca to set REBOOT=Force. If I want to suppress reboot, run msi as

```
            foo.msi /quiet REBOOT=ReallySuppress
```

And read the property from code, like

```
            String inputFile = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\foo.msi";
            // Get the type of the Windows Installer object
            Type installerType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WindowsInstaller.Installer");

            // Create the Windows Installer object
            WindowsInstaller.Installer installer = (WindowsInstaller.Installer) Activator.CreateInstance(installerType);

            // Open the MSI database in the input file
            var database = installer.OpenDatabase(inputFile, 0);

            // Open a view on the Property table for the version property
            var view = database.OpenView("SELECT * FROM `Property`");
            //View view = database.OpenView("SELECT * FROM Property");

            // Execute the view query
            view.Execute(null);

            // Get the record from the view
            Record record = view.Fetch();

            // Get the version from the data
            //string version = record.get_StringData(2);

            while (record != null)
            {
                logger.LogMessage(record.get_StringData(0) + '=' + record.get_StringData(1) + '=' + record.get_StringData(2) + '=' + record.get_StringData(3));
                record = view.Fetch();
            }
```

This doesn't work, because it always read REBOOT=Force.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out by myself.

Set **CustomActionData** to be **/reboot=[REBOOT]**.

Then read the value:

```
Context.Parameters["reboot"]
```

If /norestart option is provided, value of reboot will be **ReallySuppress**